# How to construct an IQueryable entity graph for unrelated entities without building each entity property-by-property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Currently using EF Core 2.2.x, will be moving to 3.x shortly.

Is there a way to construct an entity graph for unrelated (unrelated meaning there is no FK defined) entities without building each entity property-by-property?
I can not have a foreign key relationship defined on the database so I cannot use `.Include`.  I would like to create methods on my service layer that return entity graphs that are populated at various points in the hierarchy.  I want to avoid writing joins multiple times and setting each property of each entity since I will need to maintain this for many objects throughout my service layer.

```
class Blog
{
    int ID {get;set;}
    string Name {get;set;}
    // Many properties...

    ICollection<BlogPost> Posts {get;set;}
}

class BlogPost
{
    int ID {get;set;}
    int BlogID {get;set;}
    string Name {get;set;}
    // Many properties...

    Blog Blog {get;set;}
    ICollection<BlogPostComments> Comments {get;set;}
}

class BlogPostComment
{
    int ID {get;set;}
    int BlogPostID {get;set;}
    string Comment {get;set;}

    BlogPost BlogPost {get;set;}
}
```

The ideal solution will allow me to construct services like this:

```
public IQueryable<BlogPost> BlogPostGraph()
{
    // return BlogPosts with Comments collection populated.
}


public IQueryable<Blog> BlogGraph()
{
    // Return Blog objects with Posts and Comments collections populated.
    // Ideally this will call BlogPostGraph()
}
```

What I don't want to do:

Write the same join again and again

Construct each entity property-by-property

```
var query = from b in context.Blogs
            join p in context.BlogPosts on b.ID equals p.BlogID into blogPosts
            select new Blog
            {
                ID = b.ID,      // many properties... want to avoid constructing each entity property-by-property and maintaining this code
                Name = b.Name,  
                Posts = ??      // what here?
            }
```

Tried this  I don't see I can use it:

```
public IQueryable<Blog> BlogGraph()
{   
    var query = from b in context.Blogs
            join p in context.BlogPosts on b.ID equals p.BlogID into blogPosts
            select new { b,p }

            // next?

}
```

Comment: hi, can I ask why you can't have foreign key? Is it because of replication?

Comment: You can still configure the entity relations regardless of the foreign key setup on the database. You can follow this fluent API example: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-one-to-many-relationship-using-fluent-api-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: @daxu - the app is a little strange - aggregates data from multiple sources.  I need to be able to purge-and-recreate. Thats the short story.

Comment: @jcruz I have navigation properties on my entities but if I define relationships on the entities as the article shows than codefirst will create FK's on the database.